# Sign and upload apk with my signature

Tags: android, apk, sign, apksigner

I am facing an issue with my project. I have developed an app by developer and uploaded signed apk signed by developer's signature. Now I have updated some code myself and want to upload it on playstore with my own signature. Can I do this or not if yes then how? Thank you.

Comment: No you can't do that if the machine is different.

Comment: @DkThakur Do you have a key store file related to previous released apk ?

Comment: @Piyush what should i  do in this case

Comment: @Charuක no i dont have the keystore file

Comment: Did the developer develop the app his own PC ? If he had then you need to generate sign APK with his machine if you don't want to use different package name.

Comment: @Piyush yes he signed with his own pc and now i want to sign it with my pc with my private key.

Comment: @Piyush the machine doesn't matter but the `keystore file` should be same. You can generate signed apk with different machine with the same `keystore file`.

Comment: @DkThakur if you don't have previous keystore file then you can't update your app.

Comment: @Kaushik I know.. He has already told. So i have suggested to him

Comment: @Piyush ok dada

Answer (score 0):

You can create new keystore file to upload same apk no matter same machine or different machine. It required unique keystore file otherwise it update old apk that installed.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create new keystore  and you have to change your app package name and you have to upload  like a fresh application

Comment: No i want to use same package name

Comment: do you have keystore

Comment: if you have keystore you can upload  no issue if you dont have you cant upload whith same package

Comment: i have my own keystore not developer's

Comment: sighned apk are you able  to genrate.means you have signed apk

Comment: sorry this masssage from google clearly telling your key was diffrent

Comment: you can get with the help of google  if you khow information of account

Comment: if you lose key means forget to upload in palystore with same package name there is no way to publish whith wrong keystore its for sequerty reasion

Answer (score 0):

if you signed it with a different keystore, it will be a new application. So you should tell your users that they have to download the new version of the app.

**If you have some luck you can recover your keystore password by [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/).
 I do not guarantee that.** (if you have lost only your password).

**Reply from google team for same apk with different keystore**

> Thank you for your note. If you've lost your keystore you'll have to
>   publish the app with a new package name and a new key. You should also
>   update the description of the original app and unpublish it. Please
>   note that users are allowed unlimited reinstalls of each application
>   distributed via Google Play, an application will remain available to
>   users that have already installed it even after it has been
>   unpublished. Currently we do not support the deletion of apps or the
>   re-use of package names. Unfortunately, there is nothing else we can
>   do to assist you further with this matter.

**What is a keystore?**

> A Java KeyStore (JKS) is a repository of security certificates –
>   either authorization certificates or public key certificates – plus
>   corresponding private keys, used for instance in SSL encryption. In
>   IBM WebSphere Application Server and Oracle WebLogic Server, a file
>   with extension jks serves as keystore.

---

> If you lost your keystore then there is no way that you can update the
>   app in play sore( it will cause a signature error )! The only way is
>   that you can create an app with a new package name upload it to store
>   and remove the old app.

Comment: that link is not to recover key-store but its password !

Comment: @Charuක sorry to mention that!!